# ImportError: cannot import name '_unicodefun' from 'click'

Tags: python, python-black

When running our lint checks with the Python [Black](https://pypi.org/project/black/) package, an error comes up:

> ImportError: cannot import name '_unicodefun' from 'click' (/Users/robot/.cache/pre-commit/repo3u71ccm2/py_env-python3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/**init**.py)`

In researching this, I found the following related issues:

- *[ImportError: cannot import name '_unicodefun' from 'click' #2976](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/2976)*
- *[ImportError: cannot import name '_unicodefun' from 'click' #6013](https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/6013)*

How can I solve this problem? Is this a false positive from the linter? Do I need to modify my code?

Comment: Just use the latest version of packages as far as you can.

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question to clarify the versions being used here? Apparently, this bug was already fixed by the most recent `black` version 2 days before the question was even asked, so not even "the most recent version at that time" is a sensible guess.

Comment: If you come here from following the Hypermodern Python article series, the solution is to update the version (rev) of black in the .pre-commit-config.yaml file to a recent verion

Answer (score 231, accepted):

This has been fixed by Black 22.3.0. Versions before that won't work with click 8.1.0.

*[Incompatible with click 8.1.0 (ImportError: cannot import name '_unicodefun' from 'click') #2964](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/2964)*

E.g.: `black.yml`

```
          python-version: 3.8
      - name: install black
        run: |
-          pip install black==20.8b1
+          pip install black==22.3.0
      - name: run black
        run: |
          black . --check --line-length 100
```

https://github.com/Clinical-Genomics/cgbeacon2/pull/221/files

As a workaround, pin `click` to the last version via `pip install --upgrade click==8.0.2`.

Answer (score 40):

If you're using `black` as part of a pre-commit hook's YAML, you can update the pre-commit file (often `.pre-commit-config.yaml`) to reference the more recent versions of black (>=22.3.0), e.g.

```yaml
# See https://pre-commit.com for more information
# See https://pre-commit.com/hooks.html for more hooks
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v3.2.0
    hooks:
    -   id: trailing-whitespace
    -   id: end-of-file-fixer
    -   id: check-yaml
    -   id: check-added-large-files
-   repo: https://github.com/psf/black
    rev: 22.3.0
    hooks:
    -   id: black
        exclude: ^dist/
```

Running pip install of a new version of `black` won't be sufficient for command-line pre-commit hooks if the YAML file pins `black` itself to a particular version... which `pre-commit` does by default.  See also [Black's GitHub Issue Tracker.](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/2964)

Answer (score 18):

If none of the above works, you might have some trouble-making cache from previous changes in your code. Try running:

```bash
pre-commit clean
pre-commit autoupdate
```

Answer (score 7):

## Fixes

Here are a couple common use cases:

#### Addressing error in pre-commit yaml

`.pre-commit-config.yaml`

```yaml
- repo: https://github.com/psf/black
  rev: 22.3.0
  hooks:
    - id: black
```

> If the issue persists in pre-commit, it's likely because an old version is being cached (as suggested [here](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/2984#issuecomment-1085199449)). Run `pre-commit clean` then `pre-commit install` to reset

#### Addressing error in pyprojct toml

`pyproject.toml`

```ini
[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
black = {version = "^22.3.0", allow-prereleases = true}

[tool.black]
# https://github.com/psf/black
target-version = ["py39"]
line-length = 120
color = true
```

## Example

*requires `pyproject.toml` above*

#### Using Makefile & Poetry

`Makefile`

```makefile
#* Poetry
.PHONY: poetry-download
poetry-download:
    curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | $(PYTHON) -

.PHONY: pre-commit-install
pre-commit-install:
    poetry run pre-commit install

#* Formatters
.PHONY: codestyle
codestyle:
    poetry run black --config pyproject.toml ./
```

`.pre-commit-config.yaml`

```yaml
default_language_version:
  python: python3.9

default_stages: [commit, push]

repos:
  - repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: black
        name: black
        entry: poetry run black --config pyproject.toml
        types: [python]
        language: system
```

#### GitHub links

The dependency conflict is described in detail in the following links

- [Issue](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/2964#issuecomment-1080974737)
- [PR Fix](https://github.com/pypa/pip-audit/pull/249)

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a click version of 8.0.2 in the additional_dependencies section for black revision 20.8b1 (which is capable of cleaning python27 code), e.g

```
- repo: https://github.com/psf/black
  rev: 20.8b1
  hooks:
    - id: black
      name: Blacken python source
      additional_dependencies: ["click==8.0.2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to [install click==8.0.4](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/2964#issuecomment-1080971383) in case you are using black to format Python 2.7 code and black update is not an option for you due to [dropped Python 2.7](https://github.com/psf/black/releases/tag/22.1.0) support.
Below is `.github/workflows/black.yml` for the GitHub action I used for a legacy python 2.7 project.

```yaml
name: Black check

on: [pull_request]

jobs:
  black-check:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    name: Black
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@master
        with:
          python-version: 3.8
      - name: install black
        run: |
          pip install click==8.0.4 black==21.9b0
      - name: run black
        run: |
          black . -t py27 --check
```