# Can't commit - ImportError: cannot import name '_unicodefun' from 'click'

Tags: python, git, click, pre-commit.com

I'm trying to commit my files using using this process:

```
git add <filename>
git commit -m "Changes made to this commit"
```

When I try to commit, I receive the following error:

```
black....................................................................Failed
- hook id: black
- exit code: 1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/danieljohnson/.cache/pre-commit/repovmer0o49/py_env-python3/bin/black", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(patched_main())
  File "/Users/danieljohnson/.cache/pre-commit/repovmer0o49/py_env-python3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/black/__init__.py", line 6606, in patched_main
    patch_click()
  File "/Users/danieljohnson/.cache/pre-commit/repovmer0o49/py_env-python3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/black/__init__.py", line 6595, in patch_click
    from click import _unicodefun  # type: ignore
ImportError: cannot import name '_unicodefun' from 'click' (/Users/danieljohnson/.cache/pre-commit/repovmer0o49/py_env-python3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/__init__.py)
```

Originally using `Click` version 8.0.3, then upgraded to 22.3.0, and also tried 8.1.3, because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71673404/importerror-cannot-import-name-unicodefun-from-click) thread. However, I'm still getting the same error.

Any idea why I'm unable to commit? Could it have something to do with my changes?

Answer (score 3):

You need to update the `black` pre-commit hook to a newer version. At time of writing, the latest version is `22.3.0`

```yaml
-   repo: https://github.com/psf/black
    rev: 22.3.0
    # ...
```

Or, to do this automatically (for all hooks) run:

```bash
pre-commit autoupdate
```

Be sure to `git add` your `.pre-commit-config.yaml` after changing it.

You must make this change through the pre-commit hook configuration. Running `pip install` for newer versions of click or black won't necessarily affect the packages in the virtualenv used by `pre-commit`.

If you still have issues, consider clearing your pre-commit cache with `pre-commit clean` (though this shouldn't be necessary)

Comment: Is there a way to do this withough commiting .pre-commit-config.yaml? I don't want to overwrite the .pre-commit-config.yaml that is already in gitlab

Comment: @DanielJohnson I realize this is a late reply – technically you can just stage `.pre-commit-config.yaml` without committing and then unstage it later, but that will get messy. You could do `git commit --no-verify` if really needed, but why can't you update the pre-commit config in the repo itself?